# Uploading SharePoint app into Microsoft AppSource

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have two SharePoint apps (SharePoint hosted and Provider hosted) which I need to upload to Microsoft AppSource. I have never done this before and need a good reference article that explains about "Uploading SharePoint app into Microsoft AppSource".

How long does it take to upload your SharePoint app including all prerequisites, configuration, any code change that might required prior to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstanding what is the purpose of AppSource and which kind of apps available.
The main purpose is to help organization to find corresponding line-of-business Software for their business needs. This software must adhere Software as a Service (SaaS) architecture and must use Azure Active Directory for that purpose. Since many customers are in cloud and they are using Azure AD, they can integrate LOB software seamlessly.

Take a look at this [page](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/partners#getStarted) and click on "App review guidelines" to see all the requirements.

According to the requirements, "*Your app must allow Azure Active Directory federated single sign-on*", that means that you are not able to submit SharePoint app into the AppSource. You have two choices here:

1. Rewrite your apps as Azure AD apps and SaaS to adhere MS policies for AppSource
2. Or use [office store](https://store.office.com/en-us/appshome.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) where you are allowed to put SharePoint apps. [here is more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220033.aspx) regarding app submission to office store.

**UPD**:
It is definitely possible to convert an app to Azure AD app.  I can recommend you to start reading about authentication options supported by Azure AD [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios). What you need to do is obtain Azure AD authentication (normally Bearer header) and attach it to every request to SharePoint.
Here also good overview by Chris around [SharePoint addin vs Azure AD app](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/12/office-365-apps-and-sharepoint-apps-comparison.html)

Comment: Thanks @Kai for the response. Is it possible to convert my SharePoint app to Azure AD app? If yes then how? Pls note we are using SharePoint list to read and write data.

Comment: Updated my answer